# System.BadImageFormatException: 64bit MVC 2 project - with step by step instruction to reproduce the error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

I want to create a 64bit ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application and reference it with a 64bit class library.
But doing so I get a "System.BadImageFormatException"-Exception

Every project/Solution I add is .Net 4.0:

1. I create a new blank solution called "MySolution"
2. I add a new project to that solution (ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application), called "MyMvcApplication", No Test unit to make it easier (Visual studio asks to create one)

**Up to this point "MyMvcApplication" is running like it should. Even when setting it to x64.**

1. I add a new project to the soltion (Class Library), called "MyClassLibrary"
2. I set "MyMvcApplication" as starting project (it should be already, but just for the complete list what I do).
3. I go to the menu Build/Configuration Manager, create a new Platform "x64" by copying from "Any CPU". Then I set both projects to x64.
4. Now I have Debug | x64 and for "MyClassLibrary" and "MyMvcApplication" the Platform to x64 and the "Build box" ticked.
5. I add a reference from "MyMvcApplication" to "MyClassLibrary" (Add reference, got to the Projects Tab and select "MyClassLibrary").

**I run the "MyMvcApplication" and get the following error:**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyClassLibrary' or one of its dependencies.
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
'MyClassLibrary' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program
with an incorrect format.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.
Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified
using the exception stack trace below. 


Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'MyClassLibrary' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = Dev\Chris
LOG: DisplayName = MyClassLibrary
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: MyClassLibrary | Domain ID: 2
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/Test/MySolution/MyMvcApplication/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = c:\Test\MySolution\MyMvcApplication\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\Test\MySolution\MyMvcApplication\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f962adb4/1764faec/MyClassLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/f962adb4/1764faec/MyClassLibrary/MyClassLibrary.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/Test/MySolution/MyMvcApplication/bin/MyClassLibrary.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

EDIT:

running "corflags c:\Test\MySolution\MyMvcApplication\bin\MyClassLibrary.DLL" like suggested from  bobbymcr in the visual studio command prompt I get:

```
Version   : v4.0.30319
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32+
CorFlags  : 1
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 0
Signed    : 0
```

But I don't know what to do with this information :-(

EDIT2:

When switching all projects to x86 and running the ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application I get the following error:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this
request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your
source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MyMvcApplication.MvcApplication'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
Inherits="MyMvcApplication.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>


Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1
```

So I get an error no matter if I switch to x86 or x64.

What can I do?

Comment: Are you using Cassini or IIS to run this site?

Comment: Open up a Visual Studio command prompt and check the output of `corflags c:\Test\MySolution\MyMvcApplication\bin\MyClassLibrary.DLL`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov:I think I am using cassini (when this is the one that is installed in visual studio)

Comment: @bobbymcr I have added the information you requested (beside the fact that I don't know what that is)

Comment: Is your class library also compiled in x64 ?

Comment: @Yochai Timmer: Yes, my class libracry is set to compile with x64. I have set it to x64 in the configuration manager (For all solution plattforms). And I have ticked the build-box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact is that x64 bit application can load both x86 and x64 assemblies. But x86 application can load ONLY x86 assemblies. Casini (Visual Studio Development Server) is x86 application, that's why it does not support x64 Web applications to run. You must host x64 Web Applications only on IIS which support both x86 and x64.

Also make sure that Target platform for your class library is ".NET Framework 4.0" but not ".Net 4.0 Client profile".

Please mark this post as Answer if it resolve the issue.